# Change value inside array

Tags: json, jolt

How can I overwrite value inside array `regions` with JOLT?

```json
{
  "targetings": {
    "geo": {
      "regions": [
        150
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve this?

```json
{
  "targetings": {
    "geo": {
      "regions": [
        1000
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried with:

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "targetings": {
      "geo": {
        "regions": [
          150
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Value changed, but array symbols `[]` disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add one more level such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

meanwhile no need to repeat the key names.

**Edit** ( based on your comment : *I met another case. If there are many items inside regions array. Like: [150, 200, 300] and I need to replace it with [1500, 2000, 3000]. How it will work?* ) :

You might use **shift** transformation followed by a **modify** transformation in that case such that :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "#1500|#2000|#3000": "&3.&2.&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // need conversion to get rid of strings and make them numeric values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=toInteger"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or we can make it to reach result straightforward by using **`toList`** function within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toList(1500,2000,3000)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I met another case. If there are many items inside `regions` array. Like: [150, 200, 300] and I need to replace it with [1500, 2000, 3000]. How it will work?

Comment: Hi @fujidaon , I've just edited it, take care ...